# List to a csv file in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, file

I have a question about how to save a list as a CSV file in my way:

I have a large list with many columns:

ex. `['2020-03-01T21:46:56Z', '059d422b-9da1-4be4-836b-dca71e44ff24', '23.595858333333336', '37.95288666666667', '', '', '0', '80', 'PERIOXH', 0.0005636937949292874]`

Although I don't want to save the last column : `0.0005636937949292874`

How can I do it?
Here is my code:

```
with open(save_file, 'w', newline='\n') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(result_buffer)
```

Comment: if result_buffer is your list you can simply do result_buffer[:-1] to remove last element of the list

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over your list and remove the last item for each line:

```
with open(save_file, 'w', newline='\n') as lines:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(line[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice your list

```
    list = ['2020-03-01T21:46:56Z', '059d422b-9da1-4be4-836b-dca71e44ff24', '23.595858333333336', '37.95288666666667', '', '', '0', '80', 'PERIOXH', 0.0005636937949292874]
    print(list[0:-1])
    >>>['2020-03-01T21:46:56Z', '059d422b-9da1-4be4-836b-dca71e44ff24', '23.595858333333336', '37.95288666666667', '', '', '0', '80', 'PERIOXH']
```

Answer (score 0):

I used slicing.

```
my_list = ['2020-03-01T21:46:56Z', '059d422b-9da1-4be4-836b-dca71e44ff24', 
'23.595858333333336', '37.95288666666667', '', '', '0', '80', 'PERIOXH', 
0.0005636937949292874]
import csv
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(my_list[:-1])
```

Output:

```
2020-03-01T21:46:56Z,059d422b-9da1-4be4-836b-dca71e44ff24,23.595858333333336,37.95288666666667,,,0,80,PERIOXH
```